# Invalid version descriptor "berry" while installing yarn for my project

Tags: yarnpkg, yarn-workspaces

I want to install the yarn on my windows 8 machine, I am new to Yarn. I am following the instructions to install  from the following URL

https://yarnpkg.com/getting-started/install

As per step 1, I have installed it globally.

```
C:\Users\username>yarn -v
2.0.0-rc.32
```

now for step 2, trying to install it for my project (at location D:\V2\Code Base\App1), I am getting the following error.

```
D:\V2\Code Base\App1>yarn set version berry
Usage Error: Invalid version descriptor "berry"
$ yarn set version <version>
```

also, as my other teammates are using version 1.19.1, I tried to run the following command to set the version to 1.19.1, but it gives me the following error.

```
D:\V2\Code Base\App1>yarn set version 1.19.1
➤ YN0000: Downloading https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/releases/download/v1.19.1/yarn-1.19.1.js
➤ YN0001: Error: Invalid semver version
at C:\Users\username\.yarn\releases\yarn-berry.js:16:180921
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
at async s.mktempPromise (C:\Users\username\.yarn\releases\yarn-berry.js:2:5609)
at async l (C:\Users\username\.yarn\releases\yarn-berry.js:16:180618)
at async C:\Users\username\.yarn\releases\yarn-berry.js:16:180529
at async Function.start (C:\Users\username\.yarn\releases\yarn-berry.js:16:53076)
at async g.execute (C:\Users\username\.yarn\releases\yarn-berry.js:16:180323)
at async g.validateAndExecute (C:\Users\username\.yarn\releases\yarn-berry.js:16:48146)
at async c.run (C:\Users\username\.yarn\releases\yarn-berry.js:42:55077)
at async c.runExit (C:\Users\username\.yarn\releases\yarn-berry.js:42:55211)
➤ YN0000: Failed with errors in 10.35s
```

Following is more information

```
C:\Users\username>where yarn
C:\Program Files (x86)\Yarn\bin\yarn
C:\Program Files (x86)\Yarn\bin\yarn.cmd
C:\Program Files (x86)\Yarn\bin\yarn.js
```

Please help, Please pardon for the obvious mistakes, I am very new to Yarn and package management overall.

Thanks,
Amol